# Export collection and replace field with field from another collection (aggregate?)

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, database

Using MongoChef GUI but fine in command line.

I have a collection with a structure as thus:

#### Votes

```
{ 
    "_id" : "5qgfddRubJ32pS48B", 
    "createdBy" : "HdKRfwzGriMMZgSQu", 
    "fellowId" : "yCaqt5nT3LQCBLj8j", 
}
```

I need to first look up the user in a users collection using the `createdBy` field to see if they are verified

#### Users

```
{ 
    "_id": "HdKRfwzGriMMZgSQu",
    "emails" : [
        {
            "address" : "someuser@example.com", 
            "verified" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

and additionally, get some more information from a third collection from `fellowId`

#### Fellows

```
{ 
    "_id" : "yCaqt5nT3LQCBLj8j", 
    "title" : "Fellow Title"
}
```

And have them all export as one csv or json file. How can I achieve this as a mongo query/export?

The desired output would be, for example:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "yCaqt5nT3LQCBLj8j", 
    "fellowTitle": "Fellow Title"
    "isVerified" : true
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can perform an aggregate with 2 `$lookup` to join both collections :

- 1 `$lookup` to join `users`
- 1 `$unwind` to remove users array
- 1 `$unwind` to remove user email array (as we have to check `verify`)
- 1 `$sort` to sort with `user.emails.verified`
- 1 `$group` to actually pick only the first entry (verified or not)
- 1 `$lookup` to join `fellows`
- 1 `$unwind` to remove fellows array
- 1 `$project` to format whatever format you want at the end
- 1 `$out` to export to a new collection

Query is :

```
db.votes.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "createdBy",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "user"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$user"
}, {
    $unwind: "$user.emails"
}, {
    $sort: { "user.emails.verified": -1 }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        createdBy: { $first: "$createdBy" },
        fellowId: { $first: "$fellowId" },
        user: { $first: "$user" }
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "fellows",
        localField: "fellowId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "fellow"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$fellow"
}, {
    $project: {
        "_id": 1,
        "fellowTitle": "$fellow._id",
        "isVerified": "$user.emails.verified"
    }
}, {
    $out: "results"
}])
```

Then export with :

```
mongoexport - d testDB - c results > results.json
```

Comment: Firstly - thank you. Tremendously helpful and I appreciate it. I tried to expand upon it a bit to include some other fields with no success. Here's a gist of it: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9009fc985b301f2bd7edbdec5a0986d0 but thank you regardless!

Comment: In `$group`, you need `companyId: { $first: "$companyId" }` and `teamId: { $first: "$teamId" }` see my gist  : https://gist.github.com/akinaru/311dbe17c2a57e8a07610724310bf898